# Не могу загрузить данные из сети в свою базу данных Room

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, generics, android-room

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firstkotlinproject, PID: 10537
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.example.firstkotlinproject.model.MovieDetails
        at com.example.firstkotlinproject.repository.MovieRepositoryImplNew.loadMovie(MovieRepositoryImplNew.kt:36)
        at com.example.firstkotlinproject.repository.MovieRepositoryImplNew$loadMovie$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Мое приложение имеет 2 фрагмента, первый показывает главный экран с большим количеством фильмов, второй показывает подробности о фильме, который был нажат, для передачи данных между фрагментами я использую movieId: Int.
В функции loadMovie Я пытаюсь загрузить данные в базу данных, компилятор ругается, говорит что проблема с типами и я подозреваю что проблема в функции checkResultDetails, пытался изменять типы на Any или Result всё равно ошибки, я новичок и мало работал с дженериками, поэтому и сам не совсем понимаю всего, возможно кто то подскажет что сделать, есть идея весь функционал прописать во ViewModel, но не уверен хорошая ли это затея

**Запросы для Movie**

```
@Dao
interface MovieDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Movie")
    fun getMovies(): List<MovieWithGenres>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertMovies(movies: List<MovieDbEntity>)
}
```

**Запросы для MovieDetails**

```
@Dao
interface MovieDetailsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM MovieDetails")
    fun getMovieDetails(): List<MovieDetailsWithGenresAndActors>

    @Insert()
    fun insertMovieDetails(details: List<MovieDetailsDbEntity>)
}
```

**RoomData с методами которые используются в MovieRepositoryImplNew.kt**

```
class RoomData(private val appDb: AppDataBase): LocaleDataSource {

    override suspend fun loadMovies(): List<Movie> {
        return appDb.getMoviesDao().getMovies().map { info ->
            Movie(
                id = info.movie.id,
                years = info.movie.years,
                name = info.movie.name,
                genre = info.genres.map { genreInfo ->
                    Genre(
                        id = genreInfo.id,
                        name = genreInfo.name
                    )
                },
                time = info.movie.time,
                review = info.movie.review,
                isLiked = false,
                rating = info.movie.rating,
                avatar = info.movie.avatar
            )
        }
    }

    override fun insertMovies(movieFromApi: List<Movie>) {
        val db = movieFromApi.map { movie ->
            MovieDbEntity(
                id = movie.id,
                years = movie.years,
                name = movie.name,
                time = movie.time,
                review = movie.review,
                isLiked = false,
                rating = movie.rating,
                avatar = movie.avatar
            )
        }
        appDb.getMoviesDao().insertMovies(db)
    }

    override suspend fun loadMovie(movieId: Int): List<MovieDetails> {
        return appDb.getMovieDetailsDao().getMovieDetails().map { detail ->
            MovieDetails(
                id = detail.movieDetails.detailsId,
                years = detail.movieDetails.years,
                name = detail.movieDetails.name,
                genre = detail.genre.map { genre ->
                    Genre(
                        id = genre.id,
                        name = genre.name
                    )
                },
                review = detail.movieDetails.review,
                isLiked = false,
                rating = detail.movieDetails.rating,
                detailImageRes = detail.movieDetails.detailImageRes,
                storyLine = detail.movieDetails.storyLine,
                actors = detail.actors.map { actor ->
                    Actor(
                        id = actor.id,
                        name = actor.name,
                        imageRes = actor.imageRes
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }

    override fun insertMovieDetails(detailsFromApi: List<MovieDetails>) {
        val dbDetails = detailsFromApi.map { details ->
            MovieDetailsDbEntity(
                detailsId = details.id,
                years = details.years,
                name = details.name,
                review = details.review,
                isLiked = false,
                rating = details.rating,
                detailImageRes = details.detailImageRes,
                storyLine = details.storyLine
            )
        }
        appDb.getMovieDetailsDao().insertMovieDetails(dbDetails)
    }
}
```

**MovieDetails**

```
data class MovieDetails(
    val id: Long,
    val years: Int,
    val name: String,
    val genre: List<Genre>,
    val review: Int,
    val isLiked: Boolean,
    val rating: Int,
    val detailImageRes: String?,
    val storyLine: String,
    val actors: List<Actor>
)
```

**function(loadMovie) which has to download data and insert it to my db**

```
    class MovieRepositoryImplNew(
    private val localData: LocaleDataSource,
    private val remoteData: RemoteDataSource
): MovieRepository {

    override suspend fun loadMovies(): Result<List<Movie>> {
        return checkResultDetails {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val movieDB = localData.loadMovies()
                (if (movieDB.isEmpty()) {
                    val movieFromNetwork = remoteData.loadMovies()
                    localData.insertMovies(movieFromNetwork)
                    movieFromNetwork
                } else {
                    movieDB
                })
            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun loadMovie(movieId: Int): Result<MovieDetails> {
        return checkResultDetails {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val movieDetailsDB = localData.loadMovie(movieId)
                (if (movieDetailsDB.isEmpty()) {
                    val detailsFromNetwork = remoteData.loadMovie(movieId)
                    localData.insertMovieDetails(listOf(detailsFromNetwork))
                    detailsFromNetwork
                } else {
                    movieDetailsDB
                })
            } as MovieDetails
        }
    }


}
```

**sealed class Result**

```
sealed class Result<out T>

 data class Success<T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()

 data class Error(val message: String) : Result<Nothing>()

inline fun <R> checkResultDetails(block: () -> R): Result<R> {
    return try {
        Success(block())
    }finally {
        print("Check your network connection!")
    }
}
```

**ViewModel of Fragmnet for movie details**

```
class MovieDetailViewModel(private val movieRepository: MovieRepository): ViewModel() {

    private val _loadingMovieDetailLiveData = MutableLiveData<MovieDetails?>(null)
    private val _errorMessageForMovieDetailsLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    val loadingMovieDetailLiveData : LiveData<MovieDetails?> = _loadingMovieDetailLiveData
    val errorMessageForMovieDetailsLiveData : LiveData<String> = _errorMessageForMovieDetailsLiveData

    fun loadMovie(movieId: Int){
       viewModelScope.launch {
           stateResultDetails(movieRepository.loadMovie(movieId))
       }
    }

    private fun stateResultDetails(state: Result<MovieDetails>){
        when(state){
            is Success -> _loadingMovieDetailLiveData.value = state.data
            is Error -> _errorMessageForMovieDetailsLiveData.value = state.message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ArrayList не может быть принудительно преобразован в MovieDetails. ошибка находится в loadMovie в файле MovieRepository в 36-ой строчке.

Comment: @Wlad спасибо что откликнулись на мою проблему, MovieRepository является интерфейсом от которого наследуется класс в котором находиться метод loadMovie(movieId), к сожалению не совсем понимаю решение этой ошибки

Comment: @Wlad есть метод ещё loadMovies, который по коду практически идентичен, единственно что не принимает аргумент movieId, я сейчас добавлю код, не могли бы вы осмотреть его

Comment: ArrayList не может быть принудительно преобразован в MovieDetails. вот ваша ошибка. она вылетает, когда вы делаете as MovieDetails. это все ровно если вы напиште "String as Int". вам надо самому сделать так, чтобы ArrayList превратился в MovieDetails.

Comment: @Wlad спасибо за объяснение, если я убираю "as MovieDetails" , появляется 2 ошибки "Type mismatch: inferred type is Result<Any> but Result<MovieDetails> was expected" и "Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but MovieDetails was expected" указывающие на эти строки:                     return checkResultDetails {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

Comment: @Wlad я просто совсем не понимаю почему код в loadMovies не отображает ошибок, при том что в loadMovie(movieId) они есть, хотя код практически одинаковый

Comment: @Wlad извините если вопросы некорректно поставлена, я сам это понимаю, просто вдруг у вас есть какие то мысли почему это так, я был бы безумно рад услышать

Comment: приложите модель класса MovieDetails и ответ ArrayList, который приходит

Comment: @Wlad отредактировал сверху и добавил, если я правильно понял

Comment: MovieDetails - это один объект. а из БД у вас возвращается movieDetailsDB  - массив объектов. покажите какой querry запрос у вас для localData.loadMovie и что он должен возвращать

Comment: @Wllad Всё прикрепил как вы и сказали , извините что сильно туплю, на всякий случай ещё прикреплю ссылку на ГитХаб https://github.com/OleksiiFalatiuk/MovieApp